# SerializeArray result to single array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following serializeArray using JS serializeArray function.

```
0: {name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_problem_id]", value: "471354"}
1:
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_location_id]", value: "38565"}
2:
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_priority_id]", value: "24879"}
3:
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][days_to_complete]", value: "2"}
4:
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][description]", value: "fff"}
5:
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][order_num]", value: "1"}
```

I want it into single array like below:

```
[sub_maintenance_template] => array( 
  [0] => array( 
          [maintenance_problem_id] => 471354
          [maintenance_location_id] => 38565
          [maintenance_priority_id] => 24879
          [days_to_complete] => 2
          [description] => fff
          [order_num] => 1
   ) 
)
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using $.each but it fails.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You've tagged this with js, jquery, ajax and PHP. Where's the code that actually uses those technologies? Please add your code and describe how you are sending and receiving the data.

Comment: And have you tried anything? `for` loop or anything?

Comment: _"I tried using $.each but it fails."_ - You've missed to add this part to your question. Instead of asking "do my job for me" show us what you have tried so far, and we're happy to help you to fix and understanding the problem.

Comment: Hint: Loop over array. Create a temp object and add a property to it. Property name would be `currentObj.name` and value will be `currentObj.value`.

Comment: do it before serialising if you possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var outputAry = temp = [];
var inputAry = [{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_problem_id]", value: "471354"},
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_location_id]", value: "38565"},
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][maintenance_priority_id]", value: "24879"},
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][days_to_complete]", value: "2"},
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][description]", value: "fff"},
{name: "sub_maintenance_template[1][order_num]", value: "1"}];

$(inputAry).each(function( index) {
  var text = inputAry[index].name.replace("sub_maintenance_template[1][", "").replace("]", "");
  temp[text] =  inputAry[index].value;
});
outputAry['sub_maintenance_template'] = Array(temp);
console.log(outputAry);
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What does it do? What problem does it solve? A good answer also contains an _explanation_, not just a bunch of code.